# Converting InputStream to byteArray[] and assigning it to a variable makes the byteArray[] empty

Tags: java, arrays, inputstream, fileinputstream, datainputstream

I have a standalone Spring BOOT Project which receives uploaded file as an byteArray[] and I perform validations on this byteArray[] by converting it back to InputStream and parsing through Apache Tika & removing MetaData.

```
//Controller.java

byte[] byteArray = payload.getByteArray();
InputStream inputStream = FileUploadValidation.byteArrayToInputStream(byteArray);

InputStream finalStream = FileUploadValidation.checkIfDocumentIsValid(inputStream);
    byte[] finalByteArray = StreamUtils.copyToByteArray(finalStream); // This always comes empty
    return finalByteArray;



//Method in Utility Class (FileUploadValidation.java)  to perform operation on InputStream

public static InputStream checkIfDocumentIsValid(InputStream stream){

    BodyContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler();
    Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
    ParseContext pcontext = new ParseContext();
    RarParser parser = new RarParser();
    parser.parse(stream, handler, metadata, pcontext);//This method simply parses the stream to Apache Tika PdfParser to check if it is a valid PDF and doesn't return anything.
    stripMetaData(metadata); //Removes metaData from the stream

    return stream;
}
```

I need to return the byteArray[] to another Spring Project
I can see that the finalStream in Controller.java indeed is not empty but the finalByteArray is always empty.
What am I doing wrong ?
Is it the right way to do it ?
Max File limit for uploading is set at 15MB.

Comment: An InputStream provides sequential access to bytes.  You can only read an InputStream once.  After you have read it, you’re at the end of the InputStream and there is nothing left to read.

Comment: @VGR
So you are saying, converting the byteArray[] to InputStream at 1st step is fine, 
performing operations on it is fine but I can't return that stream into a new Inputstream object to be sent somewhere  either in InputStream or byteArray[] form?

Comment: Once you have converted an InputStream to a byte array, you cannot use that InputStream ever again.

Comment: @VGR

But I am not using that inputStream again, Can you atleast have a look at my code ? I am getting byteArray, I am performing operations on it by converting it into InputStream, once I am done parsing and done removing metaData, I am converting it back to byteArray but that byteArray is coming empty
Why is that byteArray becoming empty ? Or do you have any better approach?

Comment: `parser.parse(inputstream, …)` appears to be reading the InputStream, though I can’t be certain because I don’t see any declaration of `inputstream` anywhere.

Comment: @VGR
I have corrected the code snippet, it was the same stream which was in Method Argument.
So is there anyway that I can manipulate the stream and convert that manipulated stream into a new ByteArray and send it as response ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242793/discussion-between-pankaj-kumar-and-vgr).